# Cannot extract data from NSDictionary filled with JSON Data

Tags: php, json, ios5

I have just started writing apps for IOS5. I currently have a PHP webservice that the app calls to retrieve data from database. In the database I have 3 rows at the moment, and when I go into the debugger the dictionary has 3 key/value pairs. I cannot retrieve any of the values though. My Code below:

```
NSURL *myUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://localhost/~stephen-hill9/index.php"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myUrl];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"Parsed Data: %@", json);
NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = [json objectForKey:@"Product_Desc"]; <-APP CRASHES HERE - INVALID KEY
NSLog(@"Parsed Data: %@", bodyDictionary);
```

Also, here is the data that the dictionary contains which I got from the debugger:

```
Parsed Data: (
        {
        0 = 1;
        1 = "Caromax 20HN B/F";
        2 = 51533;
        3 = 6650;
        4 = 1117760;
        5 = 1067224;
        6 = 1759741;
        7 = 1;
        8 = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        ID = 1;
        "Max_Volume" = 1759741;
        "Product_Code" = 51533;
        "Product_Desc" = "Caromax 20HN B/F";
        Pumpable = 1067224;
        Status = 1;
        "Tank_Level" = 6650;
        Updated = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
        Volume = 1117760;
    },
        {
        0 = 2;
        1 = "C1 Kerosine";
        2 = 25101;
        3 = 1258;
        4 = 146871;
        5 = 111776;
        6 = 1018590;
        7 = 2;
        8 = "2023-02-12 20:00:00";
        ID = 2;
        "Max_Volume" = 1018590;
        "Product_Code" = 25101;
        "Product_Desc" = "C1 Kerosine";
        Pumpable = 111776;
        Status = 2;
        "Tank_Level" = 1258;
        Updated = "2023-02-12 20:00:00";
        Volume = 146871;
    },
        {
        0 = 3;
        1 = "Recovered Spirit";
        2 = 87902;
        3 = 6069;
        4 = 710172;
        5 = 675078;
        6 = 1018200;
        7 = 1;
        8 = "2012-03-16 00:00:00";
        ID = 3;
        "Max_Volume" = 1018200;
        "Product_Code" = 87902;
        "Product_Desc" = "Recovered Spirit";
        Pumpable = 675078;
        Status = 1;
        "Tank_Level" = 6069;
        Updated = "2012-03-16 00:00:00";
        Volume = 710172;
    }
)
```

I hope someone is able to help - I am sure the problem must be something basic.

Many thanks in advance,

Stephen

Comment: How do you extract data from your dictionary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you 've got here is an Array of Dictionaries, not a Dictionary itself.
Try this:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = [json objectAtIndex:0];
```

Of course this will get you the first object only, but you get the idea...

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I can't find the "objectAtIndex" method for the NSDictionary though :-S

Comment: Oops... apologies - I just changed the first dictionary - json to an array and extracted the objectAtIndex into the second dictionary, and it has worked. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad that helped you :) Consider to set the answer as correct if that was what you were looking for.