# How to get a value from a JSON Object using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I can retrieve the JSON object and display it, but how do I get the value from "lat" and "lng" to use in Xcode?

My Code:

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.<WEBSITE>];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error=nil;

NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:&error];
NSLog(@"Your JSON Object: %@ Or Error is: %@", dictionary, error);
```

JSON Object:

```
(
    {
    response =         {

        lat = "52.517681";
        lng = "-115.113995";

    };
}
```

)

I cant seem to access any of the data. I've tried:

```
NSLog(@"Value : %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"response"]);
```

I've also tried a bunch of variations like

```
NSLog(@"Value : %@",[[dictionary objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"lat"]);
```

But it always ends up with a crash:

```
-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15dd8b80
```

I've noticed when I am going through debugging that 'dictionary' only consists 1 object. How do I convert my JSON object into a NSDictionary with key pairings? Is this JSON object in the wrong format or something?

Comment: Is there a key above response?  If you break point on the line and hover over the NSDictionary object you should be able to see the contents.

Comment: What do you see?  It's an array of one element containing a dictionary with one entry named "response".  That entry is in turn a dictionary containing two elements, "lat" and "lng".

Comment: Your problem is apparently that you don't peel away the array.  (What you call "dictionary" above is an array.)

Comment: dictionary __NSCFArray * @"1 object" 0x145d4fd0   [0]

Comment: It's one of the most common mistakes... The fact that you assign your object to an `NSDictionary` doesn't make it a dictionary. @HotLicks is right, your root object is an array and you should treat it as such.

Comment: How would I go about peeling away the array?

Comment: It seams that your deserialized data are not actually a dictionary but an array.
Can you try to print the string instead of deserializing it:
use NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: How do you access an array element???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735967/cannot-extract-data-from-nsdictionary-filled-with-json-data/9736066#9736066

Comment: (And go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax -- it takes 5-10 minutes.  Just understand that in an NSLog dump of Objective-C objects, while the JSON `{}` translates to the same, the JSON `[]` translates to `()`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific JSON object is an NSArray, not an NSDictionary, which is why it does not recognize the selector, and you're not getting a warning because NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData returns an id.

Try

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];
NSDictionary *dictionary = array[0];
```

Comment: @Hbombre also note that in these modern times we generally like to access dictionary objects with bracket notation such as `dictionary[@"response"]`. It's generally easier to read, but obviously a style choice so you don't have to abide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the JSON returned is not an NSDictionnary object, but an NSArray. Change your code like this :

```
NSarray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                             error:&error];
```

The responseArray contains a dictionnary object ( or many ?) then you acn acces theme like this :

```
For ( NSDictionary *dic in responseArray){
    NSDictionnary *response = [dic objectForKey@"response"];
....
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a snip from an app I wrote...basically get an **NSData** object, typically from a response, and use **NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Options:Error** which will produce an **NSDictionary**

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

//Make sure response came in
if(response != nil){
    NSError *error = nil;
    id data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];

    if([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        //Create dictionary from all the wonderful things google provides
        NSDictionary *results = data;

        //Search JSON here
        NSArray *cityAndState = [[[[results objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address_components"] valueForKey:@"short_name"];
```

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment if you feel this post can be improved.

Comment: Right, it's now nearly invisible.