# UITextView prints JSON identifier instead of desired parsed data

Tags: php, objective-c, json, xcode, xcode5

Like the title says, my UITextView is setup to print data found within "userName". Instead of behaving appropriately, it prints "userName".

PHP code:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $arr = array ('userName'=>'derekshull', 'userBio'=>'This is derekshulls bio','userSubmitted'=>'15');
    echo json_encode($arr);


?>
```

Objective C:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://techinworship.com/json.php"];
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {
        for (id element in jsonArray) {
            textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [element description]];
            // text view will contain last element from the loop
        }
    }
    else{
        textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error description]];
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Also, when run, the application does not crash and give error. However, the following is documented in the DeBug Area.

```
2014-03-24 20:20:53.258 testtest[11434:60b] Unknown class textview in Interface Builder file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't currently have a OSX computer available so I can't evaluate my code.

It seems like the array you have in you PHP code is an associative array and the JSON will be similar. When you are parsing the JSON string in your Obj-C code try assigning it to a NSDictionary, this way you will have access to the associative array.

```
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

When using the data in the `jsonArray` don't iterate it, use the NSDictionary method `objectForKey` to get get the value you want.

As an example, to get the value of `userName`, you can do this:

```
[jsonArray objectForKey: @"userName"] // jsonArray is not actually a array, but a dictionary now
```

And to change the text of the textview, you can do the following:

```
textview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonArray objectForKey: @"userName"]];
```

Ask if something is unclear!

Cheers!

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much! Really appreciate the thorough answer!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help a fella' out! :)

Comment: Wondering if I might trouble you to let me know the difference in this guys's problem and mine. I felt that we had the exact same problem, but the solution that worked for him, didn't work for me at all...?

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363182/how-to-get-a-value-from-a-json-object-using-nsjsonserialization)

Comment: @dvdowns I believe your JSON code is not the same as his. Try comparing the raw json from your PHP to the one he has.